# magento could not save attribute value after 100 records

Tags: magento, attributes

Having issue saving attribute value after few 100 records in magneto. 
Its working fine in Firefox but in chrome system freezes or became unresponsive .

Have tried all the possibility to fix problem from changing in following values of php.ini : 
post_max_size 
suhosin.post.max_vars 
suhosin.request.max_vars

changes in magneto -> admin->configuration ->web -> session cookie management ->Cookie Lifetime ->86400 value

Comment: When does this happen?  Are you importing products/customers/other?

Comment: No, just adding value in attribute option in magneto